# Renaming subdomain and keeping traffic

Tags: google-search, 301-redirect, nginx, 302-redirect

I would like to use a reverse proxy (NGINX) to redirect traffic from let's call it `SUBDOMAIN1.example.com/EXAMPLEPAGE` to `SUBDOMAIN2.example.com/EXAMPLEPAGE`

Currently, I rank position 1-2 for most keywords, but the name of the subdomain does not describe the site accurately anymore.

My question is simple. If I keep the same DNS for SUBDOMAIN1 and simply change the server to SUBDOMAIN2, but my reverse proxy redirects the traffic to the new site/subdomain, will this affect my ranking? Will my site still show up in the search results as before? I would do something like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name SUBDOMAIN1.example.com/ ;
    location /EXAMPLEPAGE {
        return 302 https://www.SUBDOMAIN2.example.com/EXAMPLEPAGE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your redirect returns a 301 http response for every URL(mean that your URL rewrite rule is done without errors) your ranking will be moved for the new URLs.(But you won't expect exactly the same rankings for every query and you might see a change).

Comment: very interesting, Do you have any sources to confirm what you wrote?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/301-redirects

Best of bests would be google documents.

Answer (score -1):

Found an article on your question - https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408845973914-Renaming-your-subdomain

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).